# javascript validate text box for numeric and string

Tags: javascript, jquery, netbeans-8

I need some help with this javascript code. I want to validate Nights tax box and name text box, so they have a value in them. The Night text box must only accept a numeric number.

Here is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    var emailPattern = /\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b/;
    //var numeric =  /^[0-9]+$/;
    var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
        
        $(":text, #error").after("<span>*</span>");
        $("arrival_date").focus();
        
    $(document).on("click", "#submit", function (e) {
        
        var valid = true;
        
        if ($("#name").val() === "") {
            $("#name").next().text("This field is required.").css({
                "color": "#FF0000",
                "font-size": "13px"
            });
            valid = false;
        }
        else {
            
            valid = true;
        }
        
        if ($("#nights").val() === "") {
            valid = false;
            $("#nights").next().text("This field is required.").css( {
                "color": "#FF0000",
                "font-size": "13px"
            });
        } else if (!regex.test("nights")) {
            $("#nights").next().text("This field is required.").css( {
                "color": "#FF0000",
                "font-size": "13px"
            });
            valid = false;
        }
        else {
            valid = true;
        }
ad
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Reservation request</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
 <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
 <script src="reservation.js"></script>
</head>
 
<body>
 <h1>Reservation Request</h1>
 <form action="response.html" method="get"
     name="reservation_form" id="reservation_form">
  <fieldset>
         <legend>General Information</legend>
         <label for="arrival_date">Arrival date:</label>
         <input type="text" name="arrival_date" id="arrival_date" autofocus><br>
         <label for="nights">Nights:</label>
         <input type="text" name="nights" id="nights"><br>
         <label>Adults:</label>
         <select name="adults" id="adults">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>                              
         </select><br>
         <label>Children:</label>
         <select name="children" id="children">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>                              
         </select><br>         
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
         <legend>Preferences</legend>
         <label>Room type:</label>
   <input type="radio" name="room" id="standard" class="left" checked>Standard&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;          
   <input type="radio" name="room" id="business" class="left">Business&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <input type="radio" name="room" id="suite" class="left last">Suite<br>
         <label>Bed type:</label>
   <input type="radio" name="bed" id="king" class="left" checked>King&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <input type="radio" name="bed" id="double" class="left last">Double Double<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="smoking" id="smoking">Smoking<br>
  </fieldset>  
  <fieldset>
      <legend>Contact Information</legend>
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
         <label for="email">Email:</label>
         <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
   <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
   <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="999-999-9999"><br>
  </fieldset>

  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Request"><br>

 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

> UPDATED Code.
>
> ```
> $(document).ready(function() {
>
> var emailPattern = /\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b/;
> //var numeric =  /^[0-9]+$/;
> var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
>
>     $(":text, #error").after("<span>*</span>");
>     $("arrival_date").focus();
>
>
> function isNumeric(n) {
>     return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
> } 
> $(document).on("click", "#submit", function (e) {
>
>     var valid = true;
>
>     if ($("#name").val() === "") {
>         $("#name").next().text("This field is required.").css({
>             "color": "#FF0000",
>             "font-size": "13px"
>         });
>         valid = false;
>     }
>
>     if ($("#nights").val() === "") {
>         valid = false;
>         $("#nights").next().text("This field is required.").css( {
>             "color": "#FF0000",
>             "font-size": "13px"
>         });
>     } else if (isNumeric("#nights")) {
>         $("#nights").next().text("This field is required.").css( {
>             "color": "#FF0000",
>             "font-size": "13px"
>         });
>         valid = false;
>     }
>
>      if (valid === false)
>          e.preventDefault();
>
> });        });
> ```

I was hopping that someone could help me

Comment: If your question is all about js, please, remove all the unnecessary code, such as css, it make the question harder to read

Comment: I just remove the css. Can you please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use existing functions to check if an input is numeric (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)):

```
function isNumeric(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

and you can use [HTML5's input type number](http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/):

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="5">
```

Your current regex won't work since it will return true for any string that contains any kind of numbers, which is not the intended behavior.

Your usage of the variable `valid` is also incorrect: as your code is now, your form input will return as valid if `#nights` is properly validated - it will ignore the result of your name's input.

Comment: So how can I fix it so it wouldn't ignore the name's input

Comment: @Jabateh Remove the `else` lines where you set `valid = true;`. `valid` is true at the start, so without else branches it will be false if any of your validations have failed (and not be overwritten to `true`).

Comment: Sorry I am new to javascript. I did what you told me, but when I but a string value (ex: a or b or th) in the Nights text box, and put some value in the name text box, and click submit. It accept it. But what I really want is to accept numeric number a words. I just update the code, Where it said UPDATED Code. Can you please, please look at it and tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Jabateh You wrote `else if (isNumeric("#nights"))`, which means it will fail when input **IS** numeric. You want the opposite: `else if (!isNumeric("#nights"))`. Don't forget to accept an answer if it has helped you.

Comment: That is true. I Finally caught that after when I took a break from my code for 10 minutes. And also I was calling my text box value before I could click the submit but. Anyway thank so much for your help.